# Manipular string com Substring

Tags: c#

Estou tentando manipular uma string

Estou executando o código:

```
string oldString = ",,,,,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008";
string newString = oldString.Substring(oldString.IndexOf("1"));
```

Eu quero que a nova string seja: "1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008"

Mas está retornando: ",1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008".

Comment: Esse código deveria funcionar: https://repl.it/repls/VillainousTallFormat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer utilizando o Trim ao invés do substring, desta forma:

```
string oldString = ",,,,,1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008";
string newString = oldString.TrimStart(',');
```